# How to model with polygons, the hinges of Medical 3-Spring Aluminium Chart Holder?

Tags: modeling

Medical 3-Spring Aluminium Chart Holder Provides Strong 3-spring closure form medical  histories.• As shown in the figure below.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for someone to produce a tutorial for you? Have you tried anything yet? If so, what have you tried? Nobody is going to write a step by step guide here.

Comment: I think the Screw modifier is made for springs

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers, they have been very useful. I am a beginner in 3D modeling. My blender challenge is to model the hinges shown in the figure. I have been able to advance with one of them (the one with the lower location), but I request your help to model the hinge of the upper location that I indicate with the red arrow in the figure.